# Return selected fields within a cakePHP model find

Tags: php, cakephp

I simply want to return all rows from a users table but selected fields, and possible concat 2 fields.

normal sql could have just been:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(`first_name`,`last_name`) AS `fullname` FROM `users`
```

But trying to achieve this in cake is a nightmare:

```
$users = $this->User->find("all") = returns everything
$users = $this->User->find("list",array("fields" => " ...) does not work either.
```

Can anyone please help me on how to use the cake model to achieve the simple query and return results

Comment: why not using virtual fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('fields' => array('CONCAT(first_name,last_name) AS fullname', 'otherfield'), 'contain' => array());
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that users is linked to a variety of other tables, so doing the above returns one massive long array. Is there a way to isolate just searching the user table?

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel yes, just pass in `contain => false`, edited my answer